# Two specific questions on Python's multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

I am trying to learn more about Python's multiple inheritance and the use of the super() function.

I used the material at https://realpython.com/python-super/ to which all credit goes. Starting from the material there, I added some print statements trying to understand what is going on. The complete code is:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        print(f'initiated rectangle, length is {length}, width is {width}, kwargs are {kwargs}')
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.length + 2 * self.width

# Here we declare that the Square class inherits from
# the Rectangle class
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
        print(f'initiated square, length is {length}, kwargs are {kwargs}')
        super().__init__(length=length, width=length, **kwargs)

class Cube(Square):
    def surface_area(self):
        face_area = super().area()
        return face_area * 6

    def volume(self):
        face_area = super().area()
        return face_area * self.length

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
        print(f'initiated triangle, base is {base}, height is {height}, kwargs are {kwargs}')
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def tri_area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

class RightPyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, base, slant_height, **kwargs):
        print(f'initiated right pyramid, base is {base}, slant_height is {slant_height}, kwargs are {kwargs}')
        self.base = base
        self.slant_height = slant_height
        kwargs["height"] = slant_height
        kwargs["length"] = base
        print(f'initiated right pyramid finished, updated kwargs are {kwargs}')
        super().__init__(base=base, **kwargs)

    def area(self):
        base_area = super().area()
        perimeter = super().perimeter()
        return 0.5 * perimeter * self.slant_height + base_area

    def area_2(self):
        base_area = super().area()
        triangle_area = super().tri_area()
        return triangle_area * 4 + base_area

pyramid = RightPyramid(base=2, slant_height=4)
```

If we run the code we get:

```py
# initiated right pyramid, base is 2, slant_height is 4, kwargs are {}  -> OK
# initiated right pyramid finished, updated kwargs are {'height': 4, 'length': 2}  -> OK
# initiated square, length is 2, kwargs are {'base': 2, 'height': 4}  -> OK
# initiated rectangle, length is 2, width is 2, kwargs are {'base': 2, 'height': 4}  -> question 1
# initiated triangle, base is 2, height is 4, kwargs are {}  -> question 2
```

I have the following two questions:

1. The `.__init__()` function of `Rectangle` calls `.super()` (that refers to `object`) with non-empty `kwargs`. Why don't we see an error that `object()` takes no arguments?
2. Why is `Triangle.__init__()` called? `Triangle` is later in the method resolution order. `Square` is earlier in the method resolution order and has an `.__init__()` function that was called. Is this some kind of special behavior that is particular to `super()`?

Comment: 1. No, `.super()` _doesn't_ refer to `object` at that point, because 2. as you say `Triangle` is later in the MRO. If you look at `RightTriangle.mro()` you can see it's the same as you've shown: `RightPyramid` -> `Square` -> `Rectangle` -> `Triangle` -> `object`.

Comment: Just to add: I understand that this post has two questions, but they are somehow related and in this way we avoid listing the same code twice. Hopefully it is more useful to other readers in this way.